# Object does not support this property of method, while parsing html document

Tags: excel, web-scraping, html-parsing, vba

I want to scrap every post heading form this blog. I am using the code bellow but it's giving me an error **"Run time error 438 object does not support this property or method"** in line

```
Cells(i, 1).Value = ele.getElementsByClassName("entry-title")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
```

The code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim bot As Object
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim ele As HTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Long

Set bot = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
bot.Open "GET", "http://themakeupblogger.com/makeup/", False
bot.send
doc.body.innerHTML = bot.responseText

For Each ele In doc.getElementsByTagName("article")
i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  Cells(i, 1).Value = ele.getElementsByClassName("entry-title")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText

Next ele
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you execute the suggested script? What's your feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot and get all the titles you are after.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim r As Long, ele As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://themakeupblogger.com/makeup/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each elem In html.getElementsByClassName("entry-title")
        With elem.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If .Length Then r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next elem

End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft XML, v6.0
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Partial results:

```
4 High-Coverage Foundations That Might As Well Be Skincare
10 Memorial Day Beauty Essentials That Belong In Your Beach Bag
Don’t Get Married Without These Wedding Day Makeup Tips (Courtesy of a Makeup Artist)
```

To get the articles from that page you can do something like:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim http As New InternetExplorer, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim r As Long, elem As Object

    With http
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://themakeupblogger.com/makeup/"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    For Each elem In html.getElementsByTagName("article")
        With elem.getElementsByTagName("h1")
            If .Length Then r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = .Item(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
        End With
        With elem.getElementsByTagName("div")(3).getElementsByTagName("p")
            If .Length Then Cells(r, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next elem

End Sub
```

This time the reference you should add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: hello, It works fine, But if i want to parse for each article tag then what will be  chaining code  to get post heading from article tag

Comment: If it works make sure to accept it as an answer by ticking the grayed out checkmark next to my answer. As for your further request concern: you meant to get the article within those `p` tags right?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. But I like to code For Each "article" tag to get p tag innertext

Comment: I'm not talking about that fact. Please see code `For Each elem In html.getElementsByTagName("article")
        Now how i will get post header and description?????
    Next elem`

Comment: Again see the edit. One thing i should let you know is: you can't select this way: `tag>class` rather the process should be `class>tag`. When you select a tag then you can no longer use class on that tag. However, if you select class then you can divert to any property except for class. Hope that helps. Btw, I've created the above scraper the way you wanted.

Comment: Yes..! This information help me a lot. Thanks man... My fault was selecting class after tag.

Comment: Sequence of parsing html is `id>class>tag` is it?

Comment: No. Not like that. In vba, if you start with a `class`,`tag` `id` or whatever in the first place, you can continue with tag name or whatever except for class. If you start with `id` then you can continue with anything except for class name. So the bottom line is: either you use `class` name as the first option or you have to continue without `class` name. You won't be able to use `class` names once you have used something else as the first option.

Comment: Thank for your valuable comment. Can you please explain , In your code you have used  `If .Length Then Cells(r, 2) = .Item(0).innerText` why `if.Length` here?

Comment: That means `if elem.length > 0`. I think I'm done here. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the whole things. Gained some knowledge from you.